# Keeping track of objects and references

Tags: c++

If we comment out the emphasized line below we get 777 in the console.
Otherwise we get some garbage like (-534532345).
My environment is Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pro.

```
class C
{
public:
    C () { x = 777; }
    void ou() {cout << x;}
protected:
    int x;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(C & rrc) : rc(rrc) {};
    void koo () {rc.ou();}
protected:
    C & rc;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    C c;
    C * pc = new C;
    A a(*pc);
    delete pc; // <<<< this line
    a.koo();

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I am seeing this behavior?

Comment: Why does this constitute a "hole" in the language? C++ is *not a safe language*, and it is not advertised as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the point you call a.koo(), you've deleted the underlying object that its `rc` reference refers to.  That's of course UB.  What happens next is likely to have consistent behavior on a given platform for a given compilation, and may even output 777 (actually, will likely output 777 since the underlying object was very recently deleted).  In your case, it seems that either the memory that had been previously allocated to _tmain()'s `pc` object has been reallocated to something else that has overwritten it, or else you're using a debug build whose memory allocator explicitly overwrites deleted/freed memory with some fixed value, typically nonzero and not all ones, but something that's otherwise recognizable like 0xAAAAAAAA or 0xDEADDEAD.  Since -534532345 is 0xE023AF07 (or 0xFFFFFFFFE023AF07), I'm guessing it's the former (the memory has been allocated to something else which has overwritten it).  Since the call to a.koo() in your example immediately follows `delete pc`, I find it surprising that it's already been overwritten so soon, but technically anything's possible since it's UB.

Comment: Can't find a source right now, but iirc `delete` in MSVC in debug builds purposely overwrites memory with garbage values, to make these errors more apparent.

Comment: @StephenLin - Interesting.  Seems like it would overwrite it with nongarbage values that are easily recognized as the signature of unallocated memory, such as 0xAAAAAAAA or 0xDEADDEAD.  Of course my code is perfect so I never see such bugs ;) but I could swear I've seen recognizable values like that on some platform somewhere for a debug build.

Comment: Hmm, might not be garbage per se--still can't find a link, unfortunately.

Comment: Here's one: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535/Inside-CRT-Debug-Heap-Management.htm

Answer (score 4):

The delete leaves you with a dangling reference, which you follow, leading to undefined behaviour. It is not a hole in C++ or MS VS. The language allows for many illegal actions to go unchecked, and leave it up to the programmer not to invoke UB.

Answer (score 4):

The code has Undefined Behavior. You are holding the reference of an object which no longer exists. So, `rc.ou()` behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete pc, then A::rc will point to garbage location and rc.ou(); will output garbage as well. This is expected behavior and it will do this regardless of the compiler you are using

Btw 99[.99]% of the time you think you've found a bug in a compiler, it really is your bug